# Typescript generic function for dynamic key and value

Tags: typescript, generics

```
const arrayToObject = <T>(array: T[], key: keyof T): Record<string, T> => {
  return array.reduce(
    (accumulator: Record<string, T>, currentValue: T) =>
      Object.assign(accumulator, {
        [(currentValue[key] as string).toString()]: currentValue,
      }),
    {} as Record<string, T>
  );
};
```

is there anyway to avoid using "as string"? how can I have type check that the value of property "key" in type T is always a string?

```
type T {
    someOtherProperty: 20,
    active: false,
   [key]: string; (the value type of the property "key" must be string)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `arrayToObject()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in both the array element type `T` *and* the relevant key type `K`, and [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` so that its property at key `K` is assignable to `string`:

```
const arrayToObject = <T extends Record<K, string>, K extends keyof T>(
  array: T[], key: K
): Record<string, T> => {
  return array.reduce<Record<string, T>>(
    (accumulator, currentValue) =>
      Object.assign(accumulator, {
        [currentValue[key]]: currentValue,
      }),
    {}
  );
};
```

That compiles without error, and you can test that it works:

```
interface Foo {
  x: number,
  y: string,
  z: boolean
}

const foos: Foo[] = [
  { x: 1, y: "a", z: true }, 
  { x: 2, y: "b", z: false }, 
  { x: 3, y: "c", z: true }
];

const obj = arrayToObject(foos, "y"); // okay

Object.entries(obj).forEach(
  ([k, v]) => console.log(k, v.x.toFixed(1), v.y.toUpperCase())
);
/* "a",  "1.0",  "A" 
   "b",  "2.0",  "B" 
   "c",  "3.0",  "C" */ 

arrayToObject(foos, "x") // error!
// ---------> ~~~~
// Types of property 'x' are incompatible.
```

Looks good.  The compiler will accept a correct call but complain if you pass it the wrong key (although it will say it's the wrong *array*, as it uses the key to check the array element type and not vice versa... but the error is clear, `foos`' elements don't have a `string`-valued `x` property).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAngFRAeQEYCsCmwsAvDADxoz4AeU+YAJhDAEqEgINkDSANDNAQBLMAHMAfP25Va9JjADW+FCABmMNOIAUAKBjwkqAFwaA2gF1+SlCe46AlCbahOZQSNH9NMYuJgBvPRgEfCgAVwQwA2QUADoQhjDgfDJnDi53MS9xbSD9LThgYDCAWzCAGzgoDn5ipHooADU4crD8ex9xPP0YHAIiWLgICCFRMAKi0oqqmoDunphTOpCwJpa202tzcxNlhubW-F55mABfe2OF-1Og+wBuHVOHnRE6BFVC-BgAMRAQOf01BMYFK2HwCEuMBsAigwiyQQAXiZsH9yvg4GBHjodKBILBVH8ICZfiALD5Fv4YECYABGfjQgBEcAZ-CRMFhbTO-Ep1IATPSTAzsCyYGyPuUIF9TtyqSYAMwCmAM4AitkcqXmZ646AwEB4cmIGIYPqEKBaAkgCD8BkoBn3bEmgYNYT4CBaPW4eyxAkIACihQAFlotJt+AA3cwdXwwbUgNGxcogURaBTh2LUWLVb5Caj4BhaGkXGBh2JxaoAVQADpXwQBhIb4LT2ZsPAD0ACpFgAZTAAcR2SuZ-CVNNiAAYRUqAIIMmA6Uw9-uC4XDhm88eThkAIVn88XA+Vm7lG9Xtdn7db2MNqGNeFN5sJ1uodpgrdbVCQHAAhDo3zAALSAUBQF+AAfuBoG-u+aAoDWzBqDAlYICANYIFAKAwAA5NQmEGF8IigCUlZVEI2DxkAA)

Answer (score 0):

This will do :

```
const arrayToObject = <T extends Record<any, string>>(array: T[], key: keyof T): Record<string, T> => {
  return array.reduce(
    (accumulator: Record<string, T>, currentValue: T) =>
      Object.assign(accumulator, {
        [currentValue[key].toString()]: currentValue,
      }),
    {}
  );
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.9.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwXAngFRAeQEYCsCmwsAvDADxoz4AeU%20YAJhDAEqEgINlxgoA0MaAgCWYAOYA%20CQApEyFAC4YaANoBdAQGt8imNpQgAZsoCUStqE5khosQLQSYxRwG8AUDBgJ8UAK4IweCRUADpvBl9gfGkPTxhZYGBfAFtfABs4KA5zdisbcXsJASSkeigANTg033wlNBMnCVi4mBwCIhC4CAhhMTAEpNSMrIQBdxaWlRLvMAqqmpV9NRCsgGUoEXFpEzUlabLK6vw%20ZriAXxMTlpcz2JMAbjcz%206A)

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that there are other properties which are not string type, I only specifically want the property "key" to be string type